# Dart - What happened to File (dart:io) in Flutter 2.2

Tags: flutter, dart

I just upgraded to latest flutter version 2.2, and now this piece of code is not working.

```
import 'dart:io';  //this line is greyed out now
.
.
file = File("${dir.path}/file.pdf"); //error: Abstract classes can't be instantiated.
```

I checked the release notes, and could not locate any breaking changes regarding this. [The Documentaion](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/File-class.html) shows the File class as abstract, and still the example says:

```
var myFile = File('file.txt');
```

What should be the alternative to replace this line?

Comment: Are you using File class in other imports?

Comment: @p2kr you leaded me to the right path.. I see the plugin Flutter Cache Manager plugin has this line : export 'package:file/file.dart' show File;

Comment: Thanks for your help p2kr... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for other imports using `File` class. You can use alias if its necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: flutter clean
Step 2: Invalidate Caches/Restart

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with flutter_cache_manager plugin, which I was importing as

```
import 'package:flutter_cache_manager/flutter_cache_manager.dart';
```

So I replaced it with

```
import 'package:flutter_cache_manager/flutter_cache_manager.dart' as FCM;
```

(Internally this plugin has a line saying:

```
export 'package:file/file.dart' show File;
```

)
that caused the issue.

Comment: You also could use `package:file`'s `File` class instead, which is a wrapper around `dart:io`'s `File` class but allows you to easily use memory-backed objects for easier testing.